# Strange Python Import Error

Tags: python, python-2.6, importerror

I am new to Python. I am getting ImportError and seem to have tried everything that's in the documentation and the various notes in this site and other

My code is structured as follows:

```
 vsm
 |
 |______bin
 |      vsmx.py
 |______site-packages
          __init__.py
        |
        |_____libs
             __init__.py
             monitor.py
```

In monitor.py I have a function named getStr and the two `__init__.py` files are empty

I have the PYTHONPATH set to vsm/site-packages & vsm/site-packages/libs. When I run from command line,  python bin/vsmx.py, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/vsmx.py", line 15, in <module>
    from libs.monitor import getStr
   File "/var/src/vsm/bin/vsmx.py", line 15, in <module>
     from libs.monitor import getStr
ImportError: No module named monitor
```

However, when I try to run this interactively, it seems to work. I tried on both windows and linux using python 2.6.1.

Any pointers will be much appreciated

Comment: libs is inside of \_\_init__.py? (following your graph)

Comment: Did you try importing from like this `import site-packages.libs.monitor` ?  I think you're missing the first part.  I always have problems with importing too.  This is assuming your current dir is bin.

Comment: If `vsm/site-packages/libs` is on your PYTHONPATH, can't you just do `import monitor`?

Answer (score 1):

ImportError: No module... is usually a very (obscure) error meaning that you have circular imports.

Module a.py:

```
 import b
```

Module b.py:

```
 import a
```

Then main.py:

```
 import a
```

This should cause ImportError: No module named a, because a is importing b and not ready when b tries to import it.